# TRL/Transformer RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am facing `RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [CUDABoolType [1, 1, 385, 385]] is at version 3; expected version 2 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!` error.

I enabled `torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)` which provides some hints about the root of the issue in the forward path, and that points to line 201 of `site-packages/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py`, in which there is no in-place operation which could be the root of the issue.

```
    def _attn(self, query, key, value, attention_mask=None, head_mask=None):
        attn_weights = torch.matmul(query, key.transpose(-1, -2))

        if self.scale_attn_weights:
            attn_weights = attn_weights / torch.full(
                [], value.size(-1) ** 0.5, dtype=attn_weights.dtype, device=attn_weights.device
            )

        # Layer-wise attention scaling
        if self.scale_attn_by_inverse_layer_idx:
            attn_weights = attn_weights / float(self.layer_idx + 1)

        if not self.is_cross_attention:
            # if only "normal" attention layer implements causal mask
            query_length, key_length = query.size(-2), key.size(-2)
            causal_mask = self.bias[:, :, key_length - query_length : key_length, :key_length]
            mask_value = torch.finfo(attn_weights.dtype).min
            # Need to be a tensor, otherwise we get error: `RuntimeError: expected scalar type float but found double`.
            # Need to be on the same device, otherwise `RuntimeError: ..., x and y to be on the same device`
            mask_value = torch.full([], mask_value, dtype=attn_weights.dtype).to(attn_weights.device)
            attn_weights = torch.where(causal_mask, attn_weights.to(attn_weights.dtype), mask_value)

        if attention_mask is not None:
            # Apply the attention mask
            attn_weights = attn_weights + attention_mask

        attn_weights = nn.functional.softmax(attn_weights, dim=-1)

        # Downcast (if necessary) back to V's dtype (if in mixed-precision) -- No-Op otherwise
        attn_weights = attn_weights.type(value.dtype)
        attn_weights = self.attn_dropout(attn_weights)

        # Mask heads if we want to
        if head_mask is not None:
            attn_weights = attn_weights * head_mask

        attn_output = torch.matmul(attn_weights, value)

        return attn_output, attn_weights
```

To reproduce the error:

1. Install the TRL package from (https://github.com/lvwerra/trl) along with the following pckages:

- transformers 4.28.1
- torch 2.0.0
- torchaudio 2.0.0
- torchvision 0.15.0
- huggingface-hub 0.13.4
- trl 0.4.2.dev0

2. Clone the package and go to `trl/examples/summarization/scripts`
3. Setup `accelerate config` like this

```
compute_environment: LOCAL_MACHINE
distributed_type: FSDP
downcast_bf16: 'no'
fsdp_config:
  fsdp_auto_wrap_policy: TRANSFORMER_BASED_WRAP
  fsdp_backward_prefetch_policy: BACKWARD_PRE
  fsdp_offload_params: false
  fsdp_sharding_strategy: 1
  fsdp_state_dict_type: FULL_STATE_DICT
  fsdp_transformer_layer_cls_to_wrap: GPT2Block
machine_rank: 0
main_training_function: main
mixed_precision: bf16
num_machines: 1
num_processes: 4
rdzv_backend: static
same_network: true
tpu_env: []
tpu_use_cluster: false
tpu_use_sudo: false
use_cpu: false
```

4. call `accelerate launch reward_summarization.py`

I also applied some ideas from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63564934/still-get-inplace-operation-error-when-i-use-clone/75625572#75625572), but no success.

I appreciate any help/comment.